# how do i get my linear regression model to predict using clf.predict?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

So ive made a model for vehicle price prediction using linear regression. 
And now i need to get it to predict prices for 5 years into the future.
how can i do it with clf.predict?

```
X = df[['Year','Engine','FuelType','Age','Transmission','Mileage']]
```

`y = df['Price']`
This is my X and y values

```
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2)

clf = LinearRegression()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

clf.predict(X_test)   

print(clf.score(X_test, y_test))
```

After this i used,

```
clf.predict([[2022,1300,0,5,0,10000]])
```

and i got `array([-5722871.63724422])`

Comment: Are you sure your model doesn't underfit? What are the predicted values for the train set? And did you try to plot the values predicted when changing only the year to see how the model behaves?

Comment: yes i plotted the graph between year and the price

Answer (score 1):

To get only positive values you should logarithm y values:

```
y_log = np.log(ytrain.values, where=(ytrain.values>0))
```

and make inverse transformation with model's predictions:

```
y_pred = exp(clf.predict(X_test))
```